# Why does Date serialize for a JSON key differently than it does for a JSON value?

Tags: groovy, jsonbuilder

With the following code:

```
def date = new Date()
println new groovy.json.JsonBuilder([(date): date]).toString()
```

The result is something like

```
{"Fri Oct 28 15:00:45 ART 2016":"2016-10-28T18:00:45+0000"}
```

I was expecting the same representation as key and as value for the same date.

Can I force the JsonBuilder to output the keys with the same format as the values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thing is, JsonBuilder will format dates using by default a `new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")` and I understand this is not what you wish to change. Since the "key" part is serialized with the `toString()` method, you have two solutions: either use `[date.format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"): date]` or use metaProgramming to overload `Date.toString()` (it will be used for every Date object, though, so you might not want that).

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But why JsonBuilder use toString in a context and SimpleDateFormat in the other? Is there a reason?

Comment: For keys (in key/value pairs), it simply uses the default string representation of the key object, which is commonly obtained with `toString()`, and there's no reason to treat `Date` values differently. But date _values_ in JSON should be formatted in a way javascript will be able to parse them (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286204/the-right-json-date-format) and so JsonBuilder treats `Date` objects accordingly.