# how to format groovy date time +0000

Tags: java, groovy

My API application does not allowed this date time format with `+0000` behind it

i have tried to format it by codes

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

def pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
def input = "2019-02-28T02:54:32.123Z"
def date = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern).parse(input)

created(date)
```

but still getting result

```
...
    "created": "2019-02-28T09:54:32+0000",
...
```

how do i make the output in this format

```
...
    "created": "2019-02-28T09:54:32.123Z",
...
```

Comment: What is `created(date)` doing?

Comment: i have jsonbuilder, then created is one of field in json. the output is json

Comment: Why would you want `2019-02-28T02:54:32.123Z` be converted to `2019-02-28T09:54:32.123Z`? Why should the time be changed by 7 hours, when both strings specify that they are in the UTC time zone, i.e. the *same* time zone?

Answer (score 0):

With your updated comments explaining that you are producing JSON, I suggest this is probably a duplicate of [Why does Date serialize for a JSON key differently than it does for a JSON value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40310789/why-does-date-serialize-for-a-json-key-differently-than-it-does-for-a-json-value)

Basically you're trying to customize the output format for your date.  If you want to do that, you can:

```
​import java.util.Date
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat 
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder

def pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'" 
def input = "2019-02-28T02:54:32.123Z"   
def date = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern).parse(input)

// everything above here is from your original question

def pattern2 = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'" 
def sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern2) 
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"))
def builder = new JsonBuilder()

builder {
  "created"(sdf.format(date)​)
}​
```

Comment: not sure your solution, how do i place the the def date from my original codes to yours

Answer (score -2):

solved it finally

```html
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")
String date = sdf.format(new Date())
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24809803)

Comment: @ChathurangaChandrasekara user12158726 is the author of the original question and instead of requesting clarification from himself this is his/her self-answer.